Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy' in flutter
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'. > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65
I try to using the furebase service (signin with google) and I got this error
Before proceeding, ensure you follow these steps:

Determine the compatible Gradle version for your Java installation by referring to the Gradle compatibility documentation available here.

Update the Gradle version in your project:

Open the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file.
Modify the distributionUrl property to point to the desired Gradle version. For example:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-<version>-bin.zip



Replace <version> with the appropriate Gradle version identified in the compatibility documentation.

Delete the .gradle folder from your user directory:

Navigate to your user directory (usually C:\Users\<YourUserName> on Windows or /Users/<YourUserName> on macOS/Linux).
Delete the .gradle folder to remove cached files and configurations.


Set JAVA_HOME as a System Path:

Ensure that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to the directory where your Java installation resides.
Add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your system's PATH environment variable to allow Gradle to locate the Java executable.



Once you've completed these steps, you can proceed to build your project with the updated Gradle version, ensuring compatibility with your Java environment.

When we download a Flutter package it creates a Flutter package folder.
What worked for me is

Go to the downloaded flutter package folder and then go to the given path - "packages\flutter_tools\gradle"
Delete the build folder
open the project in android studio the gradle files will start downloading.

After everything is successful just run the project from the editor. It will work
